# joomla NULL response while installing

Tags: php, joomla

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Installation
 * @subpackage  Controller
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2013 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

/**
 * Controller class to initialise the database for the Joomla Installer.
 *
 * @package     Joomla.Installation
 * @subpackage  Controller
 * @since       3.1
 */
class InstallationControllerInstallDatabase extends JControllerBase
{
    /**
     * Execute the controller.
     *
     * @return  void
     *
     * @since   3.1
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        // Get the application
        /* @var InstallationApplicationWeb $app */
        $app = $this->getApplication();

        // Check for request forgeries.
        JSession::checkToken() or $app->sendJsonResponse(new Exception(JText::_('JINVALID_TOKEN'), 403));

        // Get the setup model.
        $model = new InstallationModelSetup;

        // Get the options from the session
        $options = $model->getOptions();

        // Get the database model.
        $db = new InstallationModelDatabase;

        // Attempt to create the database tables.
        $return = $db->createTables($options);

        $r = new stdClass;
        $r->view = 'install';

        // Check if the database was initialised
        if (!$return)
        {
            $r->view = 'database';
        }

        $app->sendJsonResponse($r);
    }
}
```

this is the method that is executed, the response is NULL, in the JS side the script is trying to get the `token` property of this object which is `NULL`, I don't know why it comes being `NULL` any ideas?

-------------------------------------------------------------------_

Comment: maybe some modules in my WAMP server are off but which one?

Comment: Are you trying to install Joomla 3.2.1? What version of WAMP are you running? What version of Mysql and PHP are you running. Have you messed around with any of the PHP settings on WAMP before trying to install Joomla?

Comment: the version of php and mysql are the latest(recent downloaded from official site of wamp), no no settings have been altered

Comment: all the requirements before installing are green(yes), any ideas on why the code above may return NULL? its a standart joomla install function, the tables are created, but in my javascript I get an error of NULL and the installation is stopped

Comment: Which step of the installation is this on? I can't understand how you are having problems with installing a fresh copy of Joomla on the latest version of Wamp with no changes made to anything.

Comment: it is on the last step, when the installation progress bar is running, and there JSON request are maded, the progressbar stops somewhere at the middle because of the NULL error, the code above generate that error, this is the file of that code \installation\controller\install\database.php

Comment: Post an issue on the Github page for Joomla then